# Delimiting an existing series of txt's

Tags: sql, database, batch-file

I have a series of .txt files that I am trying to get into a database.

The 7th row "contains" the delimitation in dashes and spaces. Tools like excel try and space delimit based on the entire file. but rows after row 7 have spaces within the fields.

From a post I found I have managed to create a cmd.bat script to remove the first 6 rows and footer. Now I need advise on how to "delimit" the file using row7. deleting row7 afterward would be a bonus. 4 of the fields fluctuate in length so fixed field length is not and option. Would appreciate any help.

```
Report Number: ST-49                                                                            ENERGY RESOURCES CONSERVATION BOARD                                                                                    Page 1 of 1
Run Date: 01 Jan 2012                                                                              DAILY DRILLING ACTIVITY LIST                                                                                                   
                                                                                      For the Notification Period 31 Dec 2011 To 01 Jan 2012                                                                                      

      WELL ID                    WELL NAME              LICENCE  +----------------CONTRACTOR-----------------+  RIG        ACTIVITY DATE       FIELD CENTRE  BA ID               LICENSEE                NEW PROJECTED  ACTIVITY  
                                                                 BA ID                   NAME                  NUMBER                                                                                     TOTAL DEPTH     TYPE    
------------------- ----------------------------------- -------- ------ -------------------------------------- ------ ----------------------- -------------- ----- ------------------------------------- ------------- -----------
00/04-11-028-28W4/0 ECA CROSSE 4-11-28-28                0438271 0Y52   Precision Drilling Corporation            239 31 Dec 2011 10:30:00 PM Midnapore      0026  EnCana Corporation                                  Drill To LD
00/10-21-038-24W4/0 ECA HAYNES 10-21-38-24               0439238 0Y52   Precision Drilling Corporation            154 31 Dec 2011 11:00:00 PM Red Deer       0026  EnCana Corporation                                  Drill To LD
00/04-08-049-18W5/0 HUSKY MINEHEAD 4-8-49-18             0440874 0Y52   Precision Drilling Corporation            401 01 Jan 2012 01:00:00 PM Drayton Valley 0R46  Husky Oil Operations Limited                        Drill To LD


                                                                            TOTAL  - Drill To LD - Drilling to Licensed Depth                     = 15                                                                            
                                                                            TOTAL  - Re-entry    - Re-entry of an Abandoned Well                  =  0                                                                            
                                                                            TOTAL  - Resumption  - Resumption of Drilling of a Non-abandoned Well =  0                                                                            
                                                                            TOTAL  - Set Surface - Drilling to Set Surface Casing Only            =  2                                                                            

                                                                                                TOTAL NUMBER OF WELLS LISTED = 17                                                                                                 
                                                                                                      *** END OF REPORT ***
```

Comment: What tools do you expect to use?  What's the output you need?  Just starting and ending position of each field/column?  Please be more specific.

Comment: Your database should have tools for loading flat files directly. And you absolutely should be using fixed field width. The trailing spaces can be eliminated either during the load process, or via post processing in the database. There should not be any need for a batch file, although removing the footer (and perhaps header) might be useful. State what database you are using, and others can point you to the correct utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this (it might be slow, there is not to change):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "infile=file"
SET "outfile=out"
FOR /f %%a in ('^<"%infile%" find /c /v ""') do SET /a lline=%%a-9
FOR /f "usebackqskip=6delims=" %%a IN ("%infile%") DO IF NOT DEFINED line SET "line=%%a"
FOR %%a IN (%line%) DO (
    SET /a counter+=1
    FOR /f "delims=:" %%b IN ('(echo(%%~a^&echo(^)^|findstr /o $') DO SET /a $!counter!=%%b-2
)

(FOR /f "skip=6delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /n $ "%infile%"') DO IF %lline% gtr !cline! (
    SET "line=%%a"
    FOR /f "delims=:" %%b IN ("!line!") DO SET /a cline=%%b
    SET "line=!line:*:=!"
    SET /a cstart=0
    SET "Newline="
    FOR /l %%b IN (1,1,%counter%) DO (
        CALL SET "token=%%line:~!cstart!,!$%%b!%%"
        SET "flag=true"
        SET /a tstop=!$%%b!-1
        FOR /l %%c IN (!tstop!,-1,0) DO IF DEFINED flag IF NOT "!token:~%%c,1!"==" " (
            SET /a tstop=%%c+1
            FOR /f %%d IN ("!tstop!") DO SET "token=!token:~0,%%d!"
            FOR /f "tokens=*" %%d IN ("!token!") DO SET "token=%%d"
            SET "flag="
        ) ELSE (
            IF %%c equ 0 SET "token="
        )
        IF %%b equ 1 (SET "Newline="!token!"") ELSE SET "Newline=!Newline!,"!token!""
        SET /a cstart+=!$%%b!
    )
    ECHO(!Newline!
))>"%outfile%"
TYPE "%outfile%"
```

---

..output:

```
"00/04-11-028-28W4/0","ECA CROSSE 4-11-28-28","0438271","0Y52","Precision Drilling Corporation","239","31 Dec 2011 10:30:00 PM","Midnapore","0026","EnCana Corporation","","Drill To LD"
"00/10-21-038-24W4/0","ECA HAYNES 10-21-38-24","0439238","0Y52","Precision Drilling Corporation","154","31 Dec 2011 11:00:00 PM","Red Deer","0026","EnCana Corporation","","Drill To LD"
"00/04-08-049-18W5/0","HUSKY MINEHEAD 4-8-49-18","0440874","0Y52","Precision Drilling Corporation","401","01 Jan 2012 01:00:00 PM","Drayton Valley","0R46","Husky Oil Operations Limited","","Drill To LD"
```

This doesn't work with special characters like `^"!%*=~` in the infile.
You should better use [awk for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm) and set `FIELDWIDTHS` in the `BEGIN` pattern. You might combine it with [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm).

Comment: Hi Endoro, thanks for your script. I am a complete newbie so could you clarify how you are running the script please? I have been trying to put it in a .cmd file in the same directory as the .txt file. I get a couple of error's though.

Comment: C:\Users\Sean Waites\Desktop\Scripts>cmd
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file file.
!cline! was unexpected at this time.

Comment: @user2738826   yes, there was a bug, now fixed.

Comment: Thanks Endoro, where do I find the fix?

Comment: @user2738826 I put it in my answer.

Comment: Hi Endoro, thanks for the help. I have your suggestion in a cmd file in the same directory as the .txt file I am trying to work on. I still receive the errors

Comment: in the second line of the script you can find `SET "infile=file"` , just change this and put the name of your text file there: `SET "infile=textfile.txt"` .

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much, don't suppose there's a way to modify this to do it to a series of files? The out files could leverage the  orginal file names and just add something to the name to create the new series.

Comment: Hi Endoro, didn't realize it till now. But your script seems to erase the last line of data?

Comment: Please ignore my last comment. Just found how to modify the number of rows that get dropped off the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try using qualifies, i.e. " or anything that can make your application or tool to identify that column start from here. and it will ignore the delimiter with in column.

Comment: Not an answer, but just a clarification about what OP is asking advise for. Make it a comment.